# Repeat a command in vim in a specific way

Tags: vim, macros, vi

I have the following macro

```
qa \item
```

And I have the following code

```
\begin{itemize}
test1
test2
test3
\end{itemisze}
```

When I'm at 'test1' and I press `3@a` this happens:

```
\item \item \item test1
```

How can I repeat the macro `3@a` but in order to get this

```
\item test1
\item test2
\item test3
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with just that macro. All your macro does is insert `\item`. If you want to do what you are asking, you probably need to do `qa 0i\item jq` to make the macro go to the beginning of the line, perform the insertion, then move down a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can first select the visual block `test1 test2 test3` and insert `\item` before them. Just type `ctrl+v jjj I \item ESC`. The micro won't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the macro: `0i\item <esc>j`.